# Operator keyword - please interpret this line

Tags: c++, operators, keyword

```
operator const double() const { return mdValue; }
```

To add, `mdValue` is a double.

I really don't get this line. I know the `operator` keyword is used to overload operators, but I've not yet encountered a sample like the line above, so I'm confused as to what is being overloaded on that line of code.

Comment: Maybe the casting to double?.

Comment: It's a cast operator, it handles the behavior when the class is cast to a `double`. The `const` before `double` is rather pointless though.

Comment: @user657267 that's what I was wondering about. Too many const, and I'm easily confused. You should have answered it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a conversion/cast operator.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator

Comment: That was fast! Thanks!